# error:0308010C with nuxt JavaScript after usingg legacy provider

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to install vendure e-commerce and when I run yarn dev in vsf-vendure directory who operates the front page for the store I got error

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

So I using

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

And then every thing is okay but after restarting the command I got the error again
and the previous command not working again
and there's react-start in package.json just nuxt start and I was try it and not working too

And this the error logs

```
 sudo yarn dev                                                                                                                                             130 ⨯
yarn run v1.22.18
$ nuxt
ℹ VSF Starting Vue Storefront Nuxt Module                                                                                                                 22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed Vue Storefront Context plugin                                                                                                             22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed Vue Storefront SSR plugin                                                                                                                 22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed VSF Logger plugin                                                                                                                         22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed Vue Storefront E2E testing plugin                                                                                                         22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed Internationalization Cookies plugin                                                                                                       22:57:35

 WARN  useMeta is not supported in onGlobalSetup as @nuxtjs/pwa detected.                                                                                 22:57:35
See https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/307

✔ VSF Installed nuxt Composition API Module                                                                                                               22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed StorefrontUI Module                                                                                                                       22:57:35
✔ VSF Installed Performance Module                                                                                                                        22:57:35
ℹ VSF Using raw source/ESM for @vue-storefront/vendure                                                                                                    22:57:35
ℹ VSF Using raw source/ESM for @vue-storefront/core                                                                                                       22:57:35
ℹ VSF Using raw source/ESM for @storefront-ui/vue                                                                                                         22:57:35
ℹ VSF Using raw source/ESM for @storefront-ui/shared                                                                                                      22:57:35
ℹ VSF Starting Theme Module                                                                                                                               22:57:35
ℹ Middleware starting....                                                                                                                                 22:57:35
ℹ Loading integrations...                                                                                                                                 22:57:35
ℹ - Loading: vendure @vue-storefront/vendure-api/server                                                                                                   22:57:35
ℹ - Loading: vendure extension: tokenExtension                                                                                                            22:57:35
ℹ - Loading: vendure extension: localiseExtension                                                                                                         22:57:35
✔ - Integration: vendure loaded!                                                                                                                          22:57:35
✔ Integrations loaded!                                                                                                                                    22:57:35
✔ Middleware created!                                                                                                                                     22:57:35

 ERROR  (node:6514) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in '/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/@vue-storefront/nuxt-theme/package.json' of 'lib/module.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3001/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                                       22:57:35
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                          22:57:35
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                     22:57:35
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                                    22:57:35

● Client █████████████████████████ compiling (0%)  
 

◯ Server
  

node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /var/www/html/ecommerce/commecrce/my-app/vsf-vendure/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same issue with react and did the following

```json
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
```

It's not very clear if you are using Vue or React so let me know and I'll remove my answer :)

Comment: I using vue , and i solve it with Node command

Answer (score 0):

The `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` needs to be added every time you run the scripts.

Or you can add it to your own environment variable, so Node will use it in any instance it starts.